# Corda - running in-memory nodes on separate processes doesn't work

Tags: corda

In my IntelliJ project, I have two modules, which are CorDapps. I also have a run configuration for each

- Run Participant A CorDapp
- Run Participant B CorDapp

Running either of these runs the CorDapp on an in-memory node

```
package com.demo.cordapp.participant_a

import net.corda.core.utilities.getOrThrow
import net.corda.testing.driver.DriverParameters
import net.corda.testing.driver.driver
import net.corda.testing.node.User

class Application {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {

            val parameters = DriverParameters(
                    isDebug = true,
                    waitForAllNodesToFinish = true,
                    extraCordappPackagesToScan = listOf("com.demo.shared.domain")
            )

            driver(parameters) {

                startNode(
                        providedName = PARTICIPANT_1_NAME,
                        rpcUsers = listOf(User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("ALL")))
                ).getOrThrow()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I start Participant A's node first, it works fine, but I get an error for Participant B, and vice-versa. The error is as follows

> Exception in thread "main"
>   net.corda.testing.node.internal.ListenProcessDeathException: The
>   process that was expected to listen on localhost:10000 has died with
>   status: 2

My guess is that there is a port conflict as both of them are trying to use the same p2p, rpc, web ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DriverParameters` has a `portAllocation` argument that determines how the ports are assigned to nodes.

It defaults to `PortAllocation.Incremental(10000)`. For one of the nodes, you should set this to something else (e.g. `PortAllocation.Incremental(20000)`).

If you are running in debug mode, you also need to modify the `debugPortAllocation`.

Comment: That sorts out port collisions, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Can you try also modifying the `debugPortAllocation`?